# Error parsing XML: mismatched tag (Por favor necesito ayuda)

Tags: java, android, xml

Ya cerré las etiquetas pero aún me da error, cuando recopilo me dice Error parsing XML: mismatched tag. Y en el XML Copy Editor me dice esto abajo al guardar "Premature end of data in tag PreferenceScreen line 2", por favor alguien me pudiera escribir el código como yo debería ponerlo?, la verdad no sé que hago mal, soy muy novato

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen android:title="@string/GB_Mods"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:cmwmobile="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.whatsapp">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="HPWhatsApp 4.0" android:key="cat_wa">
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_preguntas" android:title="HPWhatsApp WEB" android:key="settings_faq" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_actualizaciones" android:title="@string/updatess" android:key="updates_key" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_Thanks" android:title="Donar" android:summary="Donar al desarrollador" >
            <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="https://paypal.me/Hectorc4rp" />
         </com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference>
        <PreferenceScreen android:icon="@drawable/ic_9" android:title="Contactar al desarrollador" android:summary="Habla con Héctor Paez, creador de HPWhatsApp" >
            <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=543814805749" />
        </PreferenceScreen>
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/themes">
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_descargar" android:title="@string/download_themes" android:key="download_themes" android:summary="@string/download_themes_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_temas" android:title="@string/more_preferences" android:key="themes_key" android:summary="@string/more_preferences_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_web" android:title="Más temas" android:summary="Descarga temas hechos por otras personas" >
             <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="http://www.whatsappthemes.net/search/label/GBWhatsApp%20Themes" />
        </com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference>
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/appearance">
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_1" android:title="@string/conversation_colors" android:key="chat_colors" android:summary="@string/conversation_colors_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_2" android:title="@string/chats_colors" android:key="chats_colors" android:summary="@string/chats_colors_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_3" android:title="@string/popup_colors" android:key="popup_key" android:summary="@string/popup_colors_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_4" android:title="@string/widgets" android:key="widget_key" android:summary="@string/widgets_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_5" android:title="@string/media_sharing_pref" android:key="media_sharing_key" android:summary="@string/media_sharing_pref_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_6" android:title="@string/others" android:key="others_key" android:summary="@string/others_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_7" android:title="@string/gb_lock" android:key="gb_lock" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_actualizaciones" android:title="@string/clean_whatsapp_pref" android:key="clean_whatsapp_screen" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_8" android:title="@string/read_log_pref" android:key="logs_key" />
        <ListPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_lang" android:entries="@array/language_array" android:title="@string/language_title" android:key="gb_language_key" android:defaultValue="0" android:entryValues="@array/language_values" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_temas" android:title="@string/change_font_pref" android:key="gb_fonts" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/GB_About" android:key="cat_about">
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_twitter" android:title="@string/pref_facebook" android:key="facebook" android:summary="@string/pref_sum_facebook" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_twi" android:title="@string/google_plus" android:key="google_plus" android:summary="@string/google_plus_sum" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_web" android:title="@string/pref_sum_blogger" android:key="about" android:summary="HPWhatsApp" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_twitter" android:title="Página de Facebook" android:summary="Regalanos un me gusta en Facebook" >
              <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="https://facebook.com/todo.para.android.hp" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_compartir" android:title="@string/GBShare" android:key="share" android:summary="@string/GBShareSum" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_reportar" android:title="@string/GB_Report" android:key="report" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_Thanks" android:title="@string/Thanks" android:key="Thanks" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cierra el tag `Preference` del cuarto `PreferenceCategory`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen android:title="@string/GB_Mods"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:cmwmobile="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.whatsapp">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="HPWhatsApp 4.0" android:key="cat_wa">
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_preguntas" android:title="HPWhatsApp WEB" android:key="settings_faq" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_actualizaciones" android:title="@string/updatess" android:key="updates_key" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_Thanks" android:title="Donar" android:summary="Donar al desarrollador" >
            <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="https://paypal.me/Hectorc4rp" />
         </com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference>
        <PreferenceScreen android:icon="@drawable/ic_9" android:title="Contactar al desarrollador" android:summary="Habla con Héctor Paez, creador de HPWhatsApp" >
            <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=543814805749" />
        </PreferenceScreen>
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/themes">
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_descargar" android:title="@string/download_themes" android:key="download_themes" android:summary="@string/download_themes_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_temas" android:title="@string/more_preferences" android:key="themes_key" android:summary="@string/more_preferences_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_web" android:title="Más temas" android:summary="Descarga temas hechos por otras personas" >
             <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="http://www.whatsappthemes.net/search/label/GBWhatsApp%20Themes" />
        </com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference>
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/appearance">
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_1" android:title="@string/conversation_colors" android:key="chat_colors" android:summary="@string/conversation_colors_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_2" android:title="@string/chats_colors" android:key="chats_colors" android:summary="@string/chats_colors_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_3" android:title="@string/popup_colors" android:key="popup_key" android:summary="@string/popup_colors_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_4" android:title="@string/widgets" android:key="widget_key" android:summary="@string/widgets_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_5" android:title="@string/media_sharing_pref" android:key="media_sharing_key" android:summary="@string/media_sharing_pref_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_6" android:title="@string/others" android:key="others_key" android:summary="@string/others_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_7" android:title="@string/gb_lock" android:key="gb_lock" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_actualizaciones" android:title="@string/clean_whatsapp_pref" android:key="clean_whatsapp_screen" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_8" android:title="@string/read_log_pref" android:key="logs_key" />
        <ListPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_lang" android:entries="@array/language_array" android:title="@string/language_title" android:key="gb_language_key" android:defaultValue="0" android:entryValues="@array/language_values" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_temas" android:title="@string/change_font_pref" android:key="gb_fonts" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/GB_About" android:key="cat_about">
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_twitter" android:title="@string/pref_facebook" android:key="facebook" android:summary="@string/pref_sum_facebook" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_twi" android:title="@string/google_plus" android:key="google_plus" android:summary="@string/google_plus_sum" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_web" android:title="@string/pref_sum_blogger" android:key="about" android:summary="HPWhatsApp" />



       <!-- DEBES DE CERRAR ESTE TAG QUE ESTA ABIERTO-->
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_twitter" android:title="Página de Facebook" android:summary="Regalanos un me gusta en Facebook" >



              <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="https://facebook.com/todo.para.android.hp" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_compartir" android:title="@string/GBShare" android:key="share" android:summary="@string/GBShareSum" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_reportar" android:title="@string/GB_Report" android:key="report" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_Thanks" android:title="@string/Thanks" android:key="Thanks" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Aqui el xml sin errores:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen android:title="@string/GB_Mods"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cmwmobile="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.whatsapp">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="HPWhatsApp 4.0" android:key="cat_wa">
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_preguntas" android:title="HPWhatsApp WEB" android:key="settings_faq" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_actualizaciones" android:title="@string/updatess" android:key="updates_key" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_Thanks" android:title="Donar" android:summary="Donar al desarrollador" >
            <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="https://paypal.me/Hectorc4rp" />
        </com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference>
        <PreferenceScreen android:icon="@drawable/ic_9" android:title="Contactar al desarrollador" android:summary="Habla con Héctor Paez, creador de HPWhatsApp" >
            <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=543814805749" />
        </PreferenceScreen>
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/themes">
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_descargar" android:title="@string/download_themes" android:key="download_themes" android:summary="@string/download_themes_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_temas" android:title="@string/more_preferences" android:key="themes_key" android:summary="@string/more_preferences_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_web" android:title="Más temas" android:summary="Descarga temas hechos por otras personas" >
            <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="http://www.whatsappthemes.net/search/label/GBWhatsApp%20Themes" />
        </com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference>
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/appearance">
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_1" android:title="@string/conversation_colors" android:key="chat_colors" android:summary="@string/conversation_colors_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_2" android:title="@string/chats_colors" android:key="chats_colors" android:summary="@string/chats_colors_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_3" android:title="@string/popup_colors" android:key="popup_key" android:summary="@string/popup_colors_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_4" android:title="@string/widgets" android:key="widget_key" android:summary="@string/widgets_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_5" android:title="@string/media_sharing_pref" android:key="media_sharing_key" android:summary="@string/media_sharing_pref_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_6" android:title="@string/others" android:key="others_key" android:summary="@string/others_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_7" android:title="@string/gb_lock" android:key="gb_lock" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_actualizaciones" android:title="@string/clean_whatsapp_pref" android:key="clean_whatsapp_screen" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_8" android:title="@string/read_log_pref" android:key="logs_key" />
        <ListPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_lang" android:entries="@array/language_array" android:title="@string/language_title" android:key="gb_language_key" android:defaultValue="0" android:entryValues="@array/language_values" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_temas" android:title="@string/change_font_pref" android:key="gb_fonts" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/GB_About" android:key="cat_about">
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_twitter" android:title="@string/pref_facebook" android:key="facebook" android:summary="@string/pref_sum_facebook" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_twi" android:title="@string/google_plus" android:key="google_plus" android:summary="@string/google_plus_sum" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_web" android:title="@string/pref_sum_blogger" android:key="about" android:summary="HPWhatsApp" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_twitter" android:title="Página de Facebook" android:summary="Regalanos un me gusta en Facebook" />
        <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="https://facebook.com/todo.para.android.hp" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_compartir" android:title="@string/GBShare" android:key="share" android:summary="@string/GBShareSum" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_reportar" android:title="@string/GB_Report" android:key="report" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_Thanks" android:title="@string/Thanks" android:key="Thanks" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: Mi héroe :'v por fin

Comment: @Einer es un error tipográfico.

Comment: Ok perfecto, pueden cerrarla la pregunta.